# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://blabla.net/errors/404/ with MIME type text/html

Tags: php, html, server, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to upload an image to a server but I receive the error in the title. Does anyone know why that happens or what this means?

I mean I have already read the description in the link but I have no idea why my uploads are "dubious"

Here is my code

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>form</title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <form class="" action="backend.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
      <input type="file" name="file1" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="" value="gonder">

    </form>




  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the backend php code;

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>asd</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php

    function uploadFile ($file_field = null, $check_image = false, $random_name = false) {

    //Config Section
    //Set file upload path
    $path = 'images/'; //with trailing slash
    //Set max file size in bytes
    $max_size = 10000000;
    //Set default file extension whitelist
    $whitelist_ext = array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif');
    //Set default file type whitelist
    $whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png','image/gif');

    //The Validation
    // Create an array to hold any output
    $out = array('error'=>null);

    if (!$file_field) {
      $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid form field name";
    }

    if (!$path) {
      $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid upload path";
    }

    if (count($out['error'])>0) {
      return $out;
    }

    //Make sure that there is a file
    if((!empty($_FILES[$file_field])) && ($_FILES[$file_field]['error'] == 0)) {

    // Get filename
    $file_info = pathinfo($_FILES[$file_field]['name']);
    $name = $file_info['filename'];
    $ext = $file_info['extension'];

    //Check file has the right extension
    if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist_ext)) {
      $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Extension";
    }

    //Check that the file is of the right type
    if (!in_array($_FILES[$file_field]["type"], $whitelist_type)) {
      $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Type";
    }

    //Check that the file is not too big
    if ($_FILES[$file_field]["size"] > $max_size) {
      $out['error'][] = "File is too big";
    }

    //If $check image is set as true
    if ($check_image) {
      if (!getimagesize($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'])) {
        $out['error'][] = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
      }
    }

    //Create full filename including path
    if ($random_name) {
      // Generate random filename
      $tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

      if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
        $out['error'][] = "File must have a name";
      }
      $newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;
    } else {
        $newname = $name.'.'.$ext;
    }

    //Check if file already exists on server
    if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
      $out['error'][] = "A file with this name already exists";
    }

    if (count($out['error'])>0) {
      //The file has not correctly validated
      return $out;
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {
      //Success
      $out['filepath'] = $path;
      $out['filename'] = $newname;
      return $out;
    } else {
      $out['error'][] = "Server Error!";
    }

     } else {
      $out['error'][] = "No file uploaded";
      return $out;
     }
    }


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $file = uploadFile('file', true, true);
     if (is_array($file['error'])) {
      $message = '';
      foreach ($file['error'] as $msg) {
      $message .= '<p>'.$msg.'</p>';
     }
    } else {
     $message = "File uploaded successfully".$newname;
    }
     echo $message;
    }

?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is Corb blocking the image that I try to upload? What can be done to solve this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

after the opening php tag and before everything else. 
this should enable access from "everywhere" (*)

Comment: Thank you, but I still have the same error and an output on the page: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com

Comment: i'm not sure what i'm supposed to be looking at at that site? 
It also seems that you didn't include a `<!DOCTYPE html>`at the top of your page..